# Show that the inequality is valid for infinite terms of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, real-numbers

This question comes from a Brazilian book of real analysis, which is "Introdução a Análise" (Introduction to Analysis) of Antonio Caminha. The problem is:

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers. Show that the inequality

$$ 1 + a_n > 2^{1/n}a_{n-1} $$

is true for infinity $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the inequality does not hold for infinitely many $n \in N$.
Then, $ \forall$ except finitely many $n \in N$,

the reverse inequality holds, i.e.,
 $1 + a_n \leq 2^{1/n}a_{n-1} $  -------(1)

Taking limsup on both sides, and by the positivity of the $a_n$, we get,

$ 1+ \limsup a_n \leq \limsup2^{1/n}a_{n-1}$  --- (2)

Case 1)  $ \limsup a_{n} < \infty $
Let $\limsup a_n = a$
Then by (2),
 $ 1 + a \leq a $
A contradiction. Hence the result holds.

Case 2) $ \limsup a_n  = \infty$ 
Then by (1), for all except finitely many $n \in N$,
we have $ 1+  {a_n} \leq 2^{1/n}a_{n-1}$

(say this happens $\forall n \geq N_0$ )

Multiplying by $2^{1/{n+1}} $ on both sides, we get,
$2^{1/{n+1}} + 2^{1/{n+1}}a_n \leq 2^{ 1/{n+1}} •2^{1/n}a_{n-1} \forall n \geq N_0$

Then again using the inequality (1), we get,

$ 2^{1/n+1} + 1 + a_{n+1} \leq 2^{ \frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}}a_{n-1}$

$ \Rightarrow 1+ a_{n+1} \leq 2^{ \frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}}a_{n-1}$

Continuing in this way, we obtain ,
$ 1+ a_{n+1} \leq 2^ {\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}}a_{N_0}$
$ \forall n \geq N_0$ where $f(n)$ & $g(n)$ are functions such that 
$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} =0 $  ------(3)
Hence,

$ a_{n+1} \leq 2^ {\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}} a_{N_0} + C $

$\forall n \in N$

( where the constant C is chosen according to the finitely many terms $a_n $ where $ 1\leq n \leq N_0$
By (3), since any convergent sequence is bounded,
We have,

$a_n \leq M $  $  \forall n \in N$  for some constant

$ M >0$

Contradiction to assumption that 
$\limsup a_n = \infty$
Hence proved.

Comment: "Then by $(1)$, for all except finitely many $n \in N$, we have $a_n/a_{n-1} \leq 2^{1/n}$". Why? You could circumvent this and simply take the $\limsup$ directly on both sides after dividing, getting $\limsup a_n/a_{n-1} \leq 1$ directly, but then you have the most glaring problem: "$\limsup a_n/a_{n-1} \leq 1 \implies$ (...) [eventually] $a_n/a_{n-1} \leq 1$". That isn't true.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need to correct case 2.

Comment: @Aloizio Macedo - I have corrected case (2). Thank you so much for pointing out the error in the first proof.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt **(other way to solve)**

**Ps:** this technique is  like the Gronwall inequality for sequences

Suppose that the initial inequality holds for only a finite number of coefficients, then for $n\geq n_0$, 
$$a_{n+1} \leq 2^{\frac{1}{n}}a_n-1 $$
multiply the both sides by $\prod\limits^{n}_{k=1}2^{\frac{1}{k}}$, we have
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{\prod\limits^{n}_{k=1}2^{\frac{1}{k}}} \leq \frac{2^{\frac{1}{n}}a_n}{\prod\limits^{n}_{k=1}2^{\frac{1}{k}}}-\frac{1}{\prod\limits^{n}_{k=1}2^{\frac{1}{k}}} $$
define $h(s)=\frac{a_{s}}{\prod\limits^{s-1}_{k=1}2^{\frac{1}{k}}} $, then 
$$h(s+1) \leq h(s)- \frac{1}{\prod\limits^{s}_{k=1}2^{\frac{1}{k}}}=$$
so
$$h(s+1)- h(s) \leq -\frac{1}{\prod\limits^{s}_{k=1}2^{\frac{1}{k}}} $$
apply the sum $\sum\limits^{n-1}_{s=n_0}$ in both sides, the first is telescopic
$$h(n)\leq h(n_0) - \sum\limits^{n-1}_{s=n_0}\frac{1}{2^{H_s}} $$
where $H_s=\sum\limits^{s}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$ the harmonic number.
Using the defition of $h(n)$ we have
$$a_{n} \leq 2^{H_n}\left( h(n_0)- \sum\limits^{n-1}_{s=n_0}\frac{1}{2^{H_s}}\right), $$
but $\sum\limits^{n-1}_{s=n_0}\frac{1}{2^{H_s}}$ diverges, then $a_n$ is negative for $n$ sufficiently large.
(This divergence we can see by the comparison of $H_s$ with $\ln (s)$, $H_s<1+\ln(s)$ and **cauchy condensation test**)

Comment: Alternatively, to see that $\sum\limits^{n-1}_{s=n_0}\frac{1}{2^{H_s}}$ diverges, we can use $H_s<1+\ln(s)$, which implies that $\frac{1}{2^{H_s}}>\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{s^{\ln(2)}}$. Then we can use the integral test to show that the $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{s=n_0}\frac{1}{s^{\ln(2)}}$ diverges.